# Psql can not connect to server, password authentication failed for user postgres

Tags: postgresql

I know this has been asked a lot before but none of the other answers have helped. I have tried changing the pg_hba.conf. I have tried altering the password for postgres with `sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';"`. But to do that I need password for user postgres. I have tried changing password for postgres with `sudo passwd postgres`. It still fails authenticating. I have tried using my own password when asked for it but authentication fails.

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.2

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7OM5.png)

[sudo -u postgres psql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72uDT.png)

Comment: Did you restart the database after changing the pg_hba.conf?  Did you look in the server's log file to see what it had to say?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by looking for live processes on the port postgres uses, port: 5432. Once these processes are killed postgres worked.

So..

1. `lsof -i :5432` to print any current processes that may be running as well as their PID
2. `kill -9 <PID>` to kill the process.
3. `initdb testdb` to test

NOTE: Running GUI's for postgres will take up these processes and will restart them even if you kill the process on the certain PID. Close any giu's.

If this doesn't work I suggest checking launch daemons

1. `sudo launchctl list | fgrep postgres` to print out the daemon
2. `sudo launchctl stop <printed process name>`
3. `initdb testdb` to test